# Trying to call click function on Ruby on Rails for html button

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to call html button whose name is "Giris" as you see below html code. I do not have any specific "id" for button, so i couldn't use `find_by_id("idCode").click` function.

```
<div class="form-actions">
<button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl19','')" class="btn btn-success uppercase">Giris</button>
```

Comment: what gem are you using to interact with the browser? Since this form uses Javascript for the onclick handler, you'd need something like selenium or phantom and not just mechanize/nokogiri/etc

Comment: I use Capybara and I solved the problem as coding find("button.btn.btn-success").click

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Since your code loads on browser the only language works there are html css and js. You have to make ajax request and manipulate dom based on response for your purpose or if you don't have to talk to server just write js.